# How to calculate force on impact after free fall in water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-fall

I'm trying to calculate the force of a man falling from a bridge into water below. Thus far I've calculated everything except for the force he would experience hitting the water. Would I need to do some estimation to figure it out or what? I'm a little confused with where to go from here.

The final velocity of the body would be 40.07 m/s and the mass of the body is 78 kg. I imagine that's all you would need to be able to find the force since I calculated everything else already.

Comment: That force would depend a lot on *how* the body impacts the water. A good diver would enter the water like a javelin and experience much less force than a body falling *flat* onto the water surface.

Comment: Please do not delete a question that has received little attention just so that you can re-post it. Editing the original query will bump it to the top of the active queue where it can be seen again by users that use the front-page (http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Of course, repeated edits with no purpose other than bumping a question are also discouraged.

Comment: All that said there simply *isn't* a simple answer to this question at modest speeds. It ends up depending on the shape, density, malleability of the impactor as well as depending strongly on the speed itself.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware that you could edit the question and it would bump it to the top, I figured it would be okay to repost because I think I worded the question badly the last time and people thought I meant something else because I confused them. Sorry!